# How to make date time picker with spinner in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, datetime

I am trying to make my date time picker like a spinner how can i do that ?

```
  fun showDatePicker(){

  val formatDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
  val getDate = Calendar.getInstance()
  val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(),DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ datePicker, i, i2, i3 ->
      val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
      selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, i)
      selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, i2)
      selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i3)
      formatDate.format(selectedDate.time)
      dob.text = formatDate.format(selectedDate.time)


  }, getDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), getDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), getDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
  datePicker.show()
```

this is my code but it's simple date picker like this

[date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLuyt.png)

i wanna convert it to spinnable like this

[spinnable date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sryVc.png)

Comment: https://ozcanalasalvar.medium.com/android-spinner-datepicker-52b95a56e6fc

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a date-time picker that looks like a spinner, you can use a TimePickerDialog in addition to the DatePickerDialog.

just like this:

```
fun showDateTimePicker() {
val formatDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
val getDate = Calendar.getInstance()

// Date Picker
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
    requireContext(),
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

        // Time Picker
        val timePicker = TimePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)

                // Format and display the selected date-time
                dob.text = formatDate.format(selectedDate.time)
            },
            getDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            getDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            true // set true for 24-hour format
        )
        timePicker.show()
    },
    getDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    getDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    getDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
)
datePicker.show()
```

}

I hope I can help you

Comment: It's still same as normal date picker opening a calendar :/